# add image to facebook event

Tags: android, events, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code and the event is successfully created, I want to add an image to the event. Please help!

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "This is a test event");
    params.putString("start_time", "2013-12-02T18:00:00+0530");
    params.putString("end_time", "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530");
    params.putString("description", "This is test description yeah?.");
    params.putString("location", "Mount Lavinia");
    //params.putString("location_id", "");
    params.putString("privacy_type", "OPEN");
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/events", params, "POST", new RequestListener()
```

Comment: `params.putString("picture", "ImageUrl");` does not work?

Comment: hey, how you want to add Image? by using web url or else want to upload it from your device?

Comment: i want to add from my device..

Comment: i added this: params.putString("picture", "/sdcard/cmd.png");
but does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use source parameter to add the picture to the event. Basically source tag accepts parameters in form of byte array. So **create a byte array**(use algorithm to convert picture to bytearray) and **set the source tag using putbytearray** in bundle request and call facebook request with the event id, parameter and POST method like this - `response = facebook.request(eventid + "/picture", picture_parameters, "POST");` and **don't forget to set the access token** with publish stream rights.